# Node.js SpookyJS: error executing hello.js

Tags: node.js, spookyjs

I have installed SpookyJS to execute CasperJs commands in Node.js. I Installed it with this command: `npm install spooky`, I´m using a Centos machine.

the error:

```
$ node node_modules/spooky/examples/hello.js

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The example is working. Do you have CasperJS installed and added to path?

Comment: I have installed CasperJs but not added to the path, I have added and now works!!!!! Thanks very much

Comment: Future visitors can also read the procedure described at the following QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent